# Is infinity a branch point of $\sin(\sqrt{z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

Does the function $f(z) = \sin(\sqrt{z})$ have a branch point at infinity? I'm confused because infinity is an essential singularity of $\sin(z)$, so I'm not sure how to do the usual $z\to w=1/z$ substitution and analyse the resulting function $f(w)$ at zero... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\sin(z^{1/2})}{z^{1/2}}$ is entire,

$\frac{\sin(z^{-1/2})}{z^{-1/2}}$ has an isolated (essential) singularity at $0$

thus, $\sin(z^{-1/2})$ has a branch point at $0$ and $\sin(z^{1/2})$ has a branch point at $\infty$.

Comment: can you please explain the solution a bit more? I couldn't understand.

Comment: It depends on where you are stuck

Comment: I couldn't understand why $\sin(z^{-1/2})/z^{-1/2}$ has an isolated singularity at $0$ implies $\sin(z^{-1/2})$ has a branch point at $0$. I will be grateful If you can give me some details about how it follows. Thanks!

Comment: $f(z) z^{1/2}$ is not continuous on $|z|=r$ if $f$ is continuous with no zero